# Multiple APIs with custom domain in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer, google-cloud-api-gateway

Imagine a use case where multiple REST APIs (pure API with no UI) are deployed using Cloud Run or Cloud Functions. Each API:

- is unique and for a specific outside client, which will use it for
  various unknown purposes.
- needs to be secured so that it can only be used by the corresponding
  client.

The APIs need to be available via the same custom domain, e.g.:

- api.example.com/client_1
- api.example.com/client_2

The clients are potentially many, so any solution must be possible to automate programmatically.

Is there a good approach for achieving this using GCP? I understand that an API Gateway along with Load Balancing can be used to achieve availability via a custom domain. However I’m not sure how to best tackle the security part. Using API keys seems like an option, but IIUC each key would have access to all APIs encapsulated by the Gateway in that case. Also I’m not sure if the API keys can be created programmatically in a straightforward manner using one of the GCP client libraries.

Are there better options I’m missing?

Comment: You should thing about a load balancer for scalable and entreprise grade solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using API Gateway for your use case might not be the best possible option, reason being below section of GCP documentation:

**Custom domain names are not supported for API Gateway. If you want to customize the domain name, you have to create a load balancer to use your custom domain name and then direct requests to the gateway.dev domain of your deployed API.**

This might in turn increase the costs for your application.

So, I would suggest creating your REST APIs via nodejs and deploying it over Cloud Run. Cloud Run supports canonicalizing DNS names.

**NOTE: It is still not supported in every regions, so you might want to be thoughtful about that with respect to your Latency Issues.**

Coming to the part of securing your API's below can be followed:

You can use create API Keys and configure your API to accept these keys via header/query params

To create your application's API key you can follow the google document:
https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158862?hl=en

https://medium.com/swlh/secure-apis-in-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-using-cloud-endpoints-espv2-beta-b51b1c213aea

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple APIs using the same domain even without using Load Balancers and complex coding by using OpenAPI. This [document](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/deploying-apis-subdomains) outlines the procedure for creating multiple APIs using the sub domains in GCP. There are multiple ways for applying authentication to your OpenAPI follow this [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) for enabling authentication in OpenAPI. Hope this might help you.